# Binning data in Matplotlib and plotting profile of multiplicity using binned data

Tags: python, matplotlib, profile

I have large number of events containing large number of sub-entries per event. I want to bin the sub-entries per event according to some other column and plot profile for no. of sub-entries in those particular bins.

Following is the example dataframe-

```
                    ID    T     Eta
  entry  subentry
    0        0      11    1     0.2
             1      13    2     0.4
             2      211   2     0.1
             3      2212  5     1.4
    1        0      211   1     1.2 
             1      11    2     0.1
             2      321   3     0.6
             3      13    3     0.7
             4      211   6     1.5
```

I am trying to bin the data using `Eta` column and count the multiplicity and the plot the profile with multiplicity on y-axis and `Eta` bins on x-axis.
I am able to generate a column specifying the binning using `pd.cut`. But, I am having problem in plotting profile of number of sub-entries in that particular bin.

```
   bins = np.linspace(0,1.5,0.2)
   group = df.groupby(pd.cut(df["Eta"], bins))
```

I expect output of form -

```
entry  Eta_bin  Multiplicity
  0    (0,0.2]      2
       (0.2,0.4]    1
       (0.4,0.6]    0
  1
  .
  .
```

I want to plot profile with `Eta_bin` on x-axis and `Multiplicity` on y-axis.

Comment: could you make a small dataframe with some sample data to illustrate your problem?

Comment: have you tried `group['subentry'].sum()` or `.count()` to see if it is what you are after? If not, please add your expected output for the sample data you've provided.

Comment: @Dan Added the expected output.

Comment: Ok so you want `df.groupby(pd.cut(df["Eta"], bins))['subentry'].sum()` per `entry`. It seems to me like you should be able to do it in two groupby stages, but I'm not sure what the best way to go is. But you might find it easier if you [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Comment: @Dan I created another column called `eta_bin` using `df['eta_bin'] = pd.cut(df['Eta'], np.arange(0,1.5,0.2))` and then used `df.groupby(['entry','eta_bin'])['ID'].count()` to get the desired output. But, How am I going to plot profile using this format of data where `eta_bin` contain ranges?

Comment: Check out the [`labels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) argument of `pd.cut`, you can use it to return floats say for the start, end or middle of your ranges, instead of returning the ranges themselves.